# My program is not repeating when being nested in do- while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I want to make this program repeat itself using a do while loop. However, when I run it. All I get is errors. Any help?

```
        int Col = in.nextInt();
        int Row = in.nextInt();

        do { //Start of the do loop here
        System.out.print("   *  ");
        for(int i = 1; i<=Row;i++ ) {
           System.out.format("%4d",i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

        for(int i = 1; i<=Col; i++) {
        System.out.format("%4d |",i);
        for(int j=1; j<=Row; j++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
            }
        System.out.println();
      } while (!(Col = 0) && !(Row = 0));// This is the while loop
```

}
}

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: Do you get errors when you *run* or when you *compile* your program? Also, it is usually easier to resolve errors if you tell us what these errors are. And finally: checking if a variable is equal to a value is done using `==`: e.g., `Col == 0`.

Comment: Try formatting the code and indenting it. You're missing a closing curly brace for the 'do' statement. Also, what are the errors?

Comment: First glance, if this is the entirety of your code, it looks like your braces don't line up and your `while` is on the wrong closing curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what is going on in your code :

---

**First**, In below section of your code, you never **closed** the outer loop

```
for(int i = 1; i<=Col; i++) {
        System.out.format("%4d |",i);
        for(int j=1; j<=Row; j++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
            }
        System.out.println();
} <----need this
```

**Second**, you never decrease value of Row and Col value . Your code never stop and l**oop forever**

```
Row--;
Col--;
```

**Third**,

here

```
while (!(Col = 0) && !(Row = 0));
```

It is wrong because you assign zero to Col and Row, but compiler **looking for boolean outcome**

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression); <-- need boolean experssion
```

use this if you want to check value of Col and Row are not equal to zero

```
} while (Col != 0 && Row != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code. It would help if you actually gave the errors.

Your `while` statement is on the close brace of your `for` loop. That doesn't make any sense. Also, Java doesn't allow the use of the assignment operator inside of an expression. In fact, this is specifically forbidden to prevent you from making the mistake of assigning a value when you mean to compare two values for equivalence. You also have an unbalanced set of curly braces, two of which are not formatted inside of the code block. Your code is also indented poorly, so the unbalanced braces are difficult to actually see. If you re-indented your code properly, it would be much easier to see these syntax errors.

I would edit your question, but the change is considered too trivial for SO to allow.

Try this:

```
        int Col = in.nextInt();
        int Row = in.nextInt();

        do { // Start of the do loop here
            System.out.print("   *  ");
            for(int i = 1; i<=Row; i++) {
               System.out.format("%4d", i);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

            for(int i = 1; i<=Col; i++) {
                System.out.format("%4d |",i);
                for(int j=1; j<=Row; j++) {
                    System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } while (Col != 0 && Row != 0); // This is the while loop
```

Also, using a `do-while` loop is generally a code smell. I would recommend switching to just a plain `while` loop by moving the loop condition to the beginning.

```
        int Col = in.nextInt();
        int Row = in.nextInt();

        while (Col != 0 && Row != 0) {
            System.out.print("   *  ");
            for(int i = 1; i<=Row; i++) {
               System.out.format("%4d", i);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

            for(int i = 1; i<=Col; i++) {
                System.out.format("%4d |",i);
                for(int j=1; j<=Row; j++) {
                    System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```